# Forge + Let's Encrypt - SSL issues but browser can't see it

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

We use Forge and Let's Encrypt for hosting websites. We have a staging environment to view changes and get approval from the clients before the site goes live (it's using a sub domain so it's like firm-123.parentDomain.com). When we try to launch the site by changing the domain, when we try to assign the SSL using Let's Encrypt via Forge, Forge says it's fine and there are no errors via the dashboard of Forge. However if you go to the secure version of the site, the browser throws a hissy fit and says it's not secure. If you view the SSL cert in the browser, it looks like it's trying to use the parent's domain's cert instead. Weird right?

So we looked in the error logs and this error appears:

> mv: cannot stat '/home/forge/firm-85840050.parentDomain.com': No such file or directory No config updates to processes Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. Reloaded Nginx

For some odd reason Let's Encrypt/Nginx tries to use a conf file in the home directory when we have your basic setup (in a sites-available and so on). When the domain gets set, the conf file is correct.

This only started happening a few weeks ago. We've been doing the same steps for over a year and this suddenly started happening. Restarting Nginx doesn't work either. What does work is usually time. It takes about an hour and then the SSL starts working and everything is fine. Help?

UPDATE: I did run `nginx -t` and it says everything was fine.

Comment: Edit Nginx configuratation (files)  and  nginx.service file

Comment: @gapsf to what though? Why would it automatically fix itself?

Comment: So I don't know if this helps anyone but apparently it has to do with Let's Encrypt throttling and the 'dehydration' method not capturing the throttle errors. I'll update when I know more.